# Create repeatable elements in Word

Tags: microsoft-word

I am trying to create a template for documents that need to use repeatable elements. For example, a page with 2 images in a layout design, a page with one image on the left, text on the right etc etc.

How do you create these as pre-saved layouts and just insert them when needed - much like how you can insert a cover page. Essentially I am looking for the closest equivalent to Master Pages in Indesign. I realise I will never get anything that advanced but surely there is the capacity to reuse the same elements or create your own page designs and insert them when needed. Given that Word is often used to create huge publishing documents, there must be a way to not have to re-lay out pages that use the same format.

I am using office 265 and am on the latest version of Word 2019

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a template page for each layout that can be inserted where you want in your document. You'll need to insert a section break before the insertion point and then go to the *Insert* ribbon, click on *Object* (it's located in the *Text* section of the ribbon), and select *Text from File*. When creating the templates, make sure you are using the same style template you have in the main document to avoid any formatting issues.

Comment: Hi there - this is great thanks. I have used 'smart art' - because it's easy for clients to swap the images and fields, then saved the single page as a regular document (I was a bit thrown by the word 'template') and then inserted the page using your method when I need it in the final document - so far so good 

Comment: @MrToad happy to help : )